# Calling variable inside self parameter in class method

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I wonder if we can call variable initiated in `self` in class method. For example:

```
class ABC():
    def method1(self):
        self.var1 = '123'

    @classmethod
    def callvar1(cls):
        '''print var1'''
```

I want to achieve the same output like this:

```
class ABC():

    var1 = '123'
    
    def method1(self):
        self.var1 = '123'

    @classmethod
    def callvar1(cls):
        print(cls.var1)
```

How can I access `self.var1` in `callvar1`?

Comment: No, there is no instance state in a classmethod, **that's the whole point**. You could pass the instance explicitly as another argument... seems inelegant though

Answer (score 1):

Since `callvar1` is a class method, it does not have access to `self`. This is because the method is not tied to a specific instance of the class, but rather to the class itself. Therefore, when you call the method, it does not know which instance you are referring to. As you did in the second block of the code, you must pass the object whose `var1` you would like to print to the function.

Your other option would be to not make it a class method.

Answer (score 1):

Class methods are bound to *the class itself rather* than a particular instance of it so if you're trying to access `self.var1` (an instance variable) inside the class method you're not going to have much fun.

Your best option is to simply make the method not a class method (depending on your use case):

```
>>> class ABC():
...     var1 = '123'
...     def method1(self):
...         self.var1 = '123'
...     def callvar1(self):
...         print(self.var1)
...
>>> b = ABC()
>>> b.callvar1()
123
```

Although another option is to pass an instance of the class to the class method:

```
>>> class ABC():
...     var1 = '123'
...     def method1(self):
...         self.var1 = '123'
...     @classmethod
...     def callvar1(cls, inst):
...         print(inst.var1)
...
>>> b = ABC()
>>> ABC.callvar1(b)
123
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the self keyword to access members of the class.

```
class ABC():

    var1 = '123'
    
    def method1(self):
        self.var1 = '123'

    @classmethod
    def callvar1(self):
        print(self.var1)
```